# Python 2.7 rounding vs Python 3

Tags: python

Second question regarding python2 vs python3 today, as I am having to revert back to v2 with a script I wrote for V3 and it's not working:

```
print(str(27062/1000))
```

Using python3 this returns 27.062, but under python2 it returns 27.

27.062 is the value I require, how can I do this under python2 ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a float:

```
In [1]: 27062.0/1000
Out[1]: 27.062

In [2]: float(27062)/1000
Out[2]: 27.062
```

Or you can do:

```
In [3]: from __future__ import division
```

and have the Python3-like behavior in Python2:

```
In [4]: 27062/1000
Out[4]: 27.062
```

In that case you can get integer division by using the `//` operator:

```
In [5]: 27062//1000
Out[5]: 27
```

Comment: Brilliant: from __future__ import division - that solves both the problems I have found so far, and probably others too - thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - convert to `float`. `print(str(float(27062)/1000))`

In Python 2.x, `/` is the floor division operator for integers - it returns how many times one number will go into another. In Python 3.x, the floor division operator has been changed to `//`, and `/` behaves like "normal" division.